# Add a free product if over £50

Tags: magento

Im wondering if theres anyway of adding a free item to the cart when someone spends over £50 in magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a commerical extension for this. [Buy X PromoBot](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/4025/buy_x__auto-add_y_free_)

Answer (score 2):

I used [J2T AutoAddProduct](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/j2t-design/extension/1646/j2t--automatic-product-adds-in-cart) extension for similar functionality. Works pretty well after you figure out the configuration system and it's free.

Comment: Thanks mate, i'll look into this before i make a purchase of the other.

Comment: Just to point out that page says it is no longer maintained and links to a paid version. It is cheaper than the one I found.